# How to SQL Insert IDs with PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table named MUSIC:

```
ID   SONG   ARTIST
1    Gum    Tim
2    Air    Bob
```

How can I insert a row with autoincrement ID?

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (ID, SONG, ARTIST)
VALUES (,earth, mark);
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this question?  What do you want to do in PHP?  Auto-increment is controlled by the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as ID is your autoincrement this should work.  You don't need to declare it in your field listing.

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (SONG, ARTIST) VALUES (earth, mark);
```

Comment: well I was writing the codes in a php page.. i was adding the ID in the insert field that was my error..... that solved the problm..!!  thanks!! :)

Comment: Please be sure to accept the answer that fixed your problem whether this one or another in the thread.  high acceptance rating ensures you will be helped more often.

Answer (score 1):

You could either do:

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (SONG, ARTIST) VALUES ('earth', 'mark');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (ID, SONG, ARTIST) VALUES (NULL, 'earth', 'mark');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use autoincrement ID in the SQL. Use this

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (SONG, ARTIST) VALUES (earth, mark);
```

instead, ID column will populate automatically...

Answer (score 0):

ID field should be "autoincrement", read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

And in case it's already autoincroment:

```
INSERT INTO MUSIC (SONG, ARTIST) VALUES ('Yesterday', 'Beatles');
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to set the table in sql to have a primary key. It isn't PHP's job to create the key. Then, if you need the primary key, do something like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Source:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: -1, please stop spreading the use of the mysql extension.  Please encourage the use of mysqli or PDO instead.